# Export MS Access 2010 SQL

Tags: microsoft-access

Using Microsoft Access 2010 how do I export the SQL to an SQL file?

The output should be similar to how phpMyAdmin exports SQL; a phpMyAdmin SQL export file can be imported to a database via a `source` command in MySQL.

The issue is primarily the challenge between determining if the person who created the database properly structured the data (e.g. I rarely see the id columns in many tables) or if it is Microsoft Access simply over-complicating (or over-simplifying) the view of the database. I simply need to see the exported data in a normal SQL format.

Comment: [Introduction to importing and exporting data](https://support.office.com/en-SG/Article/Introduction-to-importing-and-exporting-data-08422593-42dd-4e73-bdf1-4c21fc3aa1b0#__toc249151407) is the first result from google "access 2010 export data"

Comment: @DavidPostill External Data tab --> XML file. Post it and I'll be happy to accept it as the answer.

Comment: @DavidPostill If you do please clarify how to export all tables, trying to figure that out...lots of tables and it only exports one at a time.

Comment: Answer added. I don't know about export all tables at once ... but see the other links in the answer ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source [Introduction to importing and exporting data](https://support.office.com/en-SG/Article/Introduction-to-importing-and-exporting-data-08422593-42dd-4e73-bdf1-4c21fc3aa1b0#__toc249151407)

> This article shows you what kinds of data you can import and export by using Access, and shows you the basic steps to get started with an import or export operation.

...

> **Types of data that Access can import, link to, or export**
>
> A quick way to learn about the data formats that Access can import or
>   export is to open a database and then explore the External Data tab on
>   the ribbon.
>
> [image]
>
> 1. The Import & Link group displays icons for the data formats that Access can import from or link to.
> 2. The Export group displays icons for all the formats that Access can export data to.
>
> The following table shows which formats can be imported into, linked
>   to, or exported out of Access:

[image]

See also [How to import Access 2010 database (.accdb) into MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340457/how-to-import-access-2010-database-accdb-into-mysql) and [Automatically Generate SQL from existing MS Access table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758669/automatically-generate-sql-from-existing-ms-access-table) for other options.

Comment: The other idea would be use mySQL and link to Microsoft Access. From mySQL create your export SQL from there. With varying datatypes, I'm not sure if the XML export nor the export from mySQL by linking to Access will be give you the best results. It is easy enough to test as LAMP or WAMP is easy to install and work with.